# useEffect does not seem to run

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Somehow I can not figure out why the function inside my useEffect does not run.
There are no prints in the console, so it seems like useEffect does not run. Also, my network tab shows that the api call never gets executed.
UPDATE: The problem seems to be with the .map function. Removing it makes the useEffect run properly.

Here is the code.

```
const ExpiringCertificates = () => {
const [certificates, setCertificates] = useState('');

const getExipringCertificates = async () => {
    console.log('running function ');
    const response = await getCertificatesExpiringInMonth();
    if(response.data.status === 200)
    {
      setCertificates(response.data.certificates);          
    }     
}

useEffect(() => {      
    console.log('running useEffect');
    getExipringCertificates();
},[]);



return (
    <BlueBackground>
        <Container>
            <h2>
                Certificaten die binnen een maand verlopen
            </h2>
            <Table>

                <tr>
                    <th>Certificaat</th>
                    <th>Verloop datum</th>                            
                </tr>
                    {certificates.map(item=>(                            
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {item.name}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {item.expiryDate}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
            </Table>
        </Container>
    </BlueBackground>
)
}
```

Comment: What gets logged? Might as well put your 'running function ' log above your `await` just to make sure that promise is resolving.

Comment: Could you please share full code for better debugging?

Comment: @AjayRaja I made an edit with the full code (except imports)

Comment: @twharmon done.. nothing is printed in the console

Comment: Seems like an issue with import or component declaration. else code looks fine.

Comment: @HarshPatel Here is my useEffect import: 
import { useEffect, useState} from 'react'; It works in every other file...

Comment: @HarshPatel The problem seems to be the .map function.. Removing it makes the useEffect run properly

Comment: `const [certificates, setCertificates] = useState('');` => on startup, `certificates` is not an array, and `''.map(...)` is not going to work. If the data should be an array, initialize to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented some loading time, this made it better but not perfect.
I found out that the declaration of the use state array was wrong as well. It was a string and not an empty array, so .map could not read it.
Here is the final code:

```js
const ExpiringCertificates = () => {
    const [certificates, setCertificates] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const getExipringCertificates = async () => {
        console.log('running function ');
        const response = await getCertificatesExpiringInMonth();
        if(response.data.status === 200)
        {
          setCertificates(response.data.certificates);          
        }     
    }

    useEffect(() => {      
        console.log('running useEffect');
        getExipringCertificates();
        setIsLoading(false);
    },[]);

    if(isLoading)
    {
        return (
            <div>
                De pagina wordt geladen...
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <BlueBackground>
            <Container>
                <h2>
                    Certificaten die binnen een maand verlopen
                </h2>
                <Table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Certificaat</th>
                        <th>Verloop datum</th>                            
                    </tr>
                    
                    {certificates.length? certificates.map(item=>(                            
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {item.name}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {item.expiryDate}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))
                :
                    <div>
                        Hallo
                    </div>
                }
                    
                </Table>
            </Container>
        </BlueBackground>
    )
}
```